# Firefox Multi-Account Containers on Tor

Tags: security, add-on

Is there a way to install Firefox Multi-Account Containers addon and/or other container-based extensions on Tor Browser? Or, case it's not possible, is there any good reason for that, like a security concern?

When I try to install it I get an error saying the add-on cannot be installed because it's corrupt.

When out of Tor, containers are an important thing regarding privacy, as they allow certain websites to be kept contained, and different kinds of naviation (i.e. work & personal) to get separated cookies, sessions, etc. The reason I want it installed here is to be capable of logging into different kinds of sites without being tracked between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Multi-Account Containers and it works pretty well. (I simply installed it via the official Add-on page)
You must disable permanent private browsing mode though, containers don't work in private browsing mode.
Please be aware, that if used improperly, this poses a huge privacy/security risk, so only proceed if you know what you're doing.
I personally use the temporary container extension to have something similar to private browsing mode, while still keeping the ability to use containers.
Also its worth mentioning that containers doesn't isolate everything 100%, things like [HSTS Flags](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1253006), [OSCP Responses](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1264562), [HTTPS certificate overrides](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1249348) are still shared across all containers and except for the latter they probably won't be fixed in the foreseeable future, at least not upstream.
(I think the Tor Project has some patches for this stuff, but idk if they are/will be included in tor browser.)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Firefox-based leaks you should use different VM's with Fire Foxes. It's easy to make - or, if you want an out-of-the-box solution - try QubesOS